# Assertj Mouse clicking is working only if the windows display resolution lowered to 1366X768

Tags: java, swing, awt, awtrobot, assertj

Mouse clicking is working only when the windows display resolution is lowered during automated UI test using assertj. Is there a way to click with the default resolution?

I tried setting the preferred size of the top JFrame but still does not help

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1360, 768));
frame.setResizable(true);
```

example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("exampleCheckbox");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JCheckBox exampleCheckbox = new JCheckBox("exampleCheckbox", true);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("checkbox"));
        panel.add(exampleCheckbox);
        fr.add(panel);
    }
```

```
@Test
public void testCheckboxUISelectEventTest( )   {
FrameFixture window = new FrameFixture (fr);
window.checkBox("exampleCheckBox").click();
}
```

mouse clicking for automated UI testing should work with default windows resolution

Comment: Without a [mcve] I do not think anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. thank you for the comment updated with a simple example

Comment: [mcve] means something that we also can run to reproduce your wrong behavior. Please don't post any links, but rather create an example that reproduce your problem.